# i can't change the text color of my design although it shows in Chrome dev tool , but not in the page itself

Tags: html, css

this is my html and Css , when i try to change the text color (pourcentage , subline) it doesn't work , i tried all the priorities (even !important), chrome dev tool shows the color but chrome doesn't change it in the body of the page

html:

```css
.circle-chart__circle {
  animation: circle-chart-fill 2s reverse; /* 1 */ 
  transform: rotate(-90deg); /* 2, 3 */
  transform-origin: center; /* 4 */
}
.circle-chart__circle--negative {
  transform: rotate(-90deg) scale(1,-1); /* 1, 2, 3 */
}

.circle-chart__info {
  animation: circle-chart-appear 2s forwards;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(0.3em);
}

@keyframes circle-chart-fill {
  to { stroke-dasharray: 0 100; }
}

@keyframes circle-chart-appear {
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding-right: 1em;
  padding-left: 1em;
}
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-column-gap: 1em;
  grid-row-gap: 1em;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
}
@media (min-width: 31em) {
  .grid {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <section>
      <h2>Positive chart value</h2>
      <svg class="circle-chart" viewbox="0 0 33.83098862 33.83098862" width="200" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <circle class="circle-chart__background" stroke="#efefef" stroke-width="2" fill="none" cx="16.91549431" cy="16.91549431" r="15.91549431" />
        <circle class="circle-chart__circle" stroke="#00acc1" stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray="30,100" stroke-linecap="round" fill="none" cx="16.91549431" cy="16.91549431" r="15.91549431" />
        <g class="circle-chart__info" id="text-input">
          <text class="circle-chart__percent" x="16.91549431" y="15.5" alignment-baseline="central" text-anchor="middle" font-size="8" >30%</text>
          <text class="circle-chart__subline" x="16.91549431" y="20.5" alignment-baseline="central" text-anchor="middle" font-size="2" >Yay 30% progress!</text>
        </g>
      </svg>
    </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are working with SVG `<text>` elements, not normal HTML. This means you should be using `fill` for text coloring. `color` will not work on `<text>`.

Try using

```
.circle-chart__subline, .circle-chart__percent {
   fill: red; //Insert color of choice
}
```

```css
.circle-chart__circle {
  animation: circle-chart-fill 2s reverse; /* 1 */ 
  transform: rotate(-90deg); /* 2, 3 */
  transform-origin: center; /* 4 */
}
.circle-chart__circle--negative {
  transform: rotate(-90deg) scale(1,-1); /* 1, 2, 3 */
}

.circle-chart__info {
  animation: circle-chart-appear 2s forwards;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(0.3em);
}

.circle-chart__subline, .circle-chart__percent {
  fill: red;
}

@keyframes circle-chart-fill {
  to { stroke-dasharray: 0 100; }
}

@keyframes circle-chart-appear {
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding-right: 1em;
  padding-left: 1em;
}
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-column-gap: 1em;
  grid-row-gap: 1em;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
}
@media (min-width: 31em) {
  .grid {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <section>
      <h2>Positive chart value</h2>
      <svg class="circle-chart" viewbox="0 0 33.83098862 33.83098862" width="200" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <circle class="circle-chart__background" stroke="#efefef" stroke-width="2" fill="none" cx="16.91549431" cy="16.91549431" r="15.91549431" />
        <circle class="circle-chart__circle" stroke="#00acc1" stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray="30,100" stroke-linecap="round" fill="none" cx="16.91549431" cy="16.91549431" r="15.91549431" />
        <g class="circle-chart__info" id="text-input">
          <text class="circle-chart__percent" x="16.91549431" y="15.5" alignment-baseline="central" text-anchor="middle" font-size="8" >30%</text>
          <text class="circle-chart__subline" x="16.91549431" y="20.5" alignment-baseline="central" text-anchor="middle" font-size="2" >Yay 30% progress!</text>
        </g>
      </svg>
    </section>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you so much bro!